# How to get WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot using Microsoft graph SDk (GraphClient) in C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

In EWS `WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot` is present to get root folder details but in Graph SDK unable to find similar method. Our application supports EWS call but due to user migration to M365 this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Graph API has similar [well-known folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) but they are not defined in Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET.

When you call Graph API you need to specify the name of well-known folder.

I have a class for this.

```
public static class WellKnownFolderNames
{
    public const string Archive = "archive";
    public const string Clutter = "clutter";
    public const string Conflicts = "conflicts";
    public const string ConversationHistory = "conversationhistory";
    public const string DeletedItems = "deleteditems";
    public const string Drafts = "drafts";
    public const string Inbox = "inbox";
    public const string JunkEmail = "junkemail";
    public const string LocalFailures = "localfailures";
    public const string MsgFolderRoot = "msgfolderroot";
    public const string Outbox = "outbox";
    public const string RecoverableItemsDeletions = "recoverableitemsdeletions";
    public const string Scheduled = "scheduled";
    public const string SearchFolders = "searchfolders";
    public const string SentItems = "sentitems";
    public const string ServerFailures = "serverfailures";
    public const string SyncIssues = "syncissues";
}

await graphClient.Me.MailFolders[WellKnownFolderNames.MsgFolderRoot]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```